# HardFault during division operation STM32 (CortexM0+)

Tags: exception, stm32, division, cortex-m, fault

I have a problem with hard fault exception during division operation and cannot find any clue (STM32G061C6). When I put anywhere in my code for example:

```
int32_t a = 354;
int32_t b = 23;
int32_t c = a/b;
```

After executing line 3, code just jumps to hard fault exception.

What I know right now:

1. This happens for variables of any type.
2. code like 'int32_t c = 5/2' works fine (is it compiled to one constant?)
3. To exclude unaligned access I tried code:

->

```
int32_t * a = (int32_t*)0x20000000;
int32_t * b = (int32_t*)0x20000004;
int32_t * c = (int32_t*)0x20000008;
*c = *a/ *b;
```

And it still does not work.

4. The only not zero value of cortex registers:

->

```
 #define SYSHND_CTRL  (*(volatile unsigned int*)  (0xE000ED24u))  // System Handler Control and State Register
 #define NVIC_MFSR    (*(volatile unsigned char*) (0xE000ED28u))  // Memory Management Fault Status Register
 #define NVIC_BFSR    (*(volatile unsigned char*) (0xE000ED29u))  // Bus Fault Status Register
 #define NVIC_UFSR    (*(volatile unsigned short*)(0xE000ED2Au))  // Usage Fault Status Register
 #define NVIC_HFSR    (*(volatile unsigned int*)  (0xE000ED2Cu))  // Hard Fault Status Register
 #define NVIC_DFSR    (*(volatile unsigned int*)  (0xE000ED30u))  // Debug Fault Status Register
 #define NVIC_BFAR    (*(volatile unsigned int*)  (0xE000ED38u))  // Bus Fault Manage Address Register
 #define NVIC_AFSR    (*(volatile unsigned int*)  (0xE000ED3Cu))  // Auxiliary Fault Status Register
```

is DFSR where VCHATCH is 1.

---

I should mention that I you my own linker script, startup file and makefile. Can the problem be there, for example with compilation flags?

```
MARCH   = cortex-m0plus 
CFLAGS  = -g -c -mcpu=$(MARCH) -mthumb -std=gnu17 -O0 -Wall -Wno-main -Wno-misleading-indentation
```

I would be glad for any hint, thanks.

---

Edit:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
main/main.c:
15  void main(void){
   0x08000af8 <+0>: 80 b5   push    {r7, lr}
   0x08000afa <+2>: 84 b0   sub sp, #16
   0x08000afc <+4>: 00 af   add r7, sp, #0

16      int a = 2;
   0x08000afe <+6>: 02 23   movs    r3, #2
   0x08000b00 <+8>: fb 60   str r3, [r7, #12]

17      int b = 5;
   0x08000b02 <+10>:    05 23   movs    r3, #5
   0x08000b04 <+12>:    bb 60   str r3, [r7, #8]

18      int c = a/b;
   0x08000b06 <+14>:    b9 68   ldr r1, [r7, #8]
   0x08000b08 <+16>:    f8 68   ldr r0, [r7, #12]
   0x08000b0a <+18>:    05 f0 a9 f9 bl  0x8005e60 <__divsi3>
   0x08000b0e <+22>:    03 00   movs    r3, r0
   0x08000b10 <+24>:    7b 60   str r3, [r7, #4]

19    /*  //init 
20      initTicker();  
21      initDelayTim();
22      delayMs(100);        //pockat na napajeni
23      adc_init();
24      pwm_init();
25      spi_init();
26      //loop*/
27      while(1){
   0x08000b12 <+26>:    fe e7   b.n 0x8000b12 <main+26>
End of assembler dump.
```

---

```
Dump of assembler code for function __divsi3:
   0x08005e60 <+0>: 00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005e62 <+2>: 51 e3   b.n 0x8006508
   0x08005e64 <+4>: 43 00   lsls    r3, r0, #1
   0x08005e66 <+6>: 00 0a   lsrs    r0, r0, #8
   0x08005e68 <+8>: 01 c0   stmia   r0!, {r0}
   0x08005e6a <+10>:    20 e0   b.n 0x8005eae <__divsi3+78>
   0x08005e6c <+12>:    00 10   asrs    r0, r0, #32
   0x08005e6e <+14>:    61 42   negs    r1, r4
   0x08005e70 <+16>:    01 20   movs    r0, #1
   0x08005e72 <+18>:    51 e2   b.n 0x8006318
   0x08005e74 <+20>:    27 00   movs    r7, r4
   0x08005e76 <+22>:    00 0a   lsrs    r0, r0, #8
   0x08005e78 <+24>:    00 30   adds    r0, #0
   0x08005e7a <+26>:    b0 e1   b.n 0x80061de
   0x08005e7c <+28>:    00 30   adds    r0, #0
   0x08005e7e <+30>:    60 42   negs    r0, r4
   0x08005e80 <+32>:    01 00   movs    r1, r0
   0x08005e82 <+34>:    53 e1   b.n 0x800612c <OFFSET_TAB_CCMRx>
   0x08005e84 <+36>:    26 00   movs    r6, r4
   0x08005e86 <+38>:    00 9a   ldr r2, [sp, #0]
   0x08005e88 <+40>:    02 00   movs    r2, r0
   0x08005e8a <+42>:    11 e1   b.n 0x80060b0 <SHIFT_TAB_OISx+8>
   0x08005e8c <+44>:    28 00   movs    r0, r5
   0x08005e8e <+46>:    00 0a   lsrs    r0, r0, #8
   0x08005e90 <+48>:    0e 02   lsls    r6, r1, #8
   0x08005e92 <+50>:    11 e3   b.n 0x80064b8
   0x08005e94 <+52>:    81 11   asrs    r1, r0, #6
   0x08005e96 <+54>:    a0 01   lsls    r0, r4, #6
   0x08005e98 <+56>:    08 20   movs    r0, #8
   0x08005e9a <+58>:    a0 03   lsls    r0, r4, #14
   0x08005e9c <+60>:    01 20   movs    r0, #1
   0x08005e9e <+62>:    a0 13   asrs    r0, r4, #14
   0x08005ea0 <+64>:    01 02   lsls    r1, r0, #8
   0x08005ea2 <+66>:    51 e3   b.n 0x8006548
   0x08005ea4 <+68>:    03 00   movs    r3, r0
   0x08005ea6 <+70>:    51 31   adds    r1, #81 ; 0x51
   0x08005ea8 <+72>:    01 12   asrs    r1, r0, #8
   0x08005eaa <+74>:    a0 31   adds    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005eac <+76>:    02 22   movs    r2, #2
   0x08005eae <+78>:    a0 31   adds    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005eb0 <+80>:    fa ff ff 3a         ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xfffa3aff
   0x08005eb4 <+84>:    02 01   lsls    r2, r0, #4
   0x08005eb6 <+86>:    51 e3   b.n 0x800655c
   0x08005eb8 <+88>:    03 00   movs    r3, r0
   0x08005eba <+90>:    51 31   adds    r1, #81 ; 0x51
   0x08005ebc <+92>:    81 10   asrs    r1, r0, #2
   0x08005ebe <+94>:    a0 31   adds    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005ec0 <+96>:    82 20   movs    r0, #130    ; 0x82
   0x08005ec2 <+98>:    a0 31   adds    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005ec4 <+100>:   fa ff ff 3a         ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xfffa3aff
   0x08005ec8 <+104>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005eca <+106>:   a0 e3   b.n 0x800660e
   0x08005ecc <+108>:   01 00   movs    r1, r0
   0x08005ece <+110>:   53 e1   b.n 0x8006178
   0x08005ed0 <+112>:   01 30   adds    r0, #1
   0x08005ed2 <+114>:   43 20   movs    r0, #67 ; 0x43
   0x08005ed4 <+116>:   02 00   movs    r2, r0
   0x08005ed6 <+118>:   80 21   movs    r1, #128    ; 0x80
   0x08005ed8 <+120>:   a1 00   lsls    r1, r4, #2
   0x08005eda <+122>:   53 e1   b.n 0x8006184
   0x08005edc <+124>:   a1 30   adds    r0, #161    ; 0xa1
   0x08005ede <+126>:   43 20   movs    r0, #67 ; 0x43
   0x08005ee0 <+128>:   a2 00   lsls    r2, r4, #2
   0x08005ee2 <+130>:   80 21   movs    r1, #128    ; 0x80
   0x08005ee4 <+132>:   21 01   lsls    r1, r4, #4
   0x08005ee6 <+134>:   53 e1   b.n 0x8006190
   0x08005ee8 <+136>:   21 31   adds    r1, #33 ; 0x21
   0x08005eea <+138>:   43 20   movs    r0, #67 ; 0x43
   0x08005eec <+140>:   22 01   lsls    r2, r4, #4
   0x08005eee <+142>:   80 21   movs    r1, #128    ; 0x80
   0x08005ef0 <+144>:   a1 01   lsls    r1, r4, #6
   0x08005ef2 <+146>:   53 e1   b.n 0x800619c
   0x08005ef4 <+148>:   a1 31   adds    r1, #161    ; 0xa1
   0x08005ef6 <+150>:   43 20   movs    r0, #67 ; 0x43
   0x08005ef8 <+152>:   a2 01   lsls    r2, r4, #6
   0x08005efa <+154>:   80 21   movs    r1, #128    ; 0x80
   0x08005efc <+156>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005efe <+158>:   53 e3   b.n 0x80065a8
   0x08005f00 <+160>:   22 22   movs    r2, #34 ; 0x22
   0x08005f02 <+162>:   b0 11   asrs    r0, r6, #6
   0x08005f04 <+164>:   21 12   asrs    r1, r4, #8
   0x08005f06 <+166>:   a0 11   asrs    r0, r4, #6
   0x08005f08 <+168>:   ef ff ff 1a         ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0xffef1aff
   0x08005f0c <+172>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f0e <+174>:   5c e3   b.n 0x80065ca
   0x08005f10 <+176>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f12 <+178>:   60 42   negs    r0, r4
   0x08005f14 <+180>:   1e ff 2f e1 vrhadd.u16  d14, d14, d31
   0x08005f18 <+184>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f1a <+186>:   3c e1   b.n 0x8006196
   0x08005f1c <+188>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f1e <+190>:   60 42   negs    r0, r4
   0x08005f20 <+192>:   1e ff 2f e1 vrhadd.u16  d14, d14, d31
   0x08005f24 <+196>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f26 <+198>:   a0 33   adds    r3, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005f28 <+200>:   cc 0f   lsrs    r4, r1, #31
   0x08005f2a <+202>:   a0 01   lsls    r0, r4, #6
   0x08005f2c <+204>:   01 00   movs    r1, r0
   0x08005f2e <+206>:   80 03   lsls    r0, r0, #14
   0x08005f30 <+208>:   1e ff 2f e1 vrhadd.u16  d14, d14, d31
   0x08005f34 <+212>:   01 08   lsrs    r1, r0, #32
   0x08005f36 <+214>:   51 e3   b.n 0x80065dc
   0x08005f38 <+216>:   21 18   adds    r1, r4, r0
   0x08005f3a <+218>:   a0 21   movs    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005f3c <+220>:   10 20   movs    r0, #16
   0x08005f3e <+222>:   a0 23   movs    r3, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005f40 <+224>:   00 20   movs    r0, #0
   0x08005f42 <+226>:   a0 33   adds    r3, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005f44 <+228>:   01 0c   lsrs    r1, r0, #16
   0x08005f46 <+230>:   51 e3   b.n 0x80065ec
   0x08005f48 <+232>:   21 14   asrs    r1, r4, #16
   0x08005f4a <+234>:   a0 21   movs    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005f4c <+236>:   08 20   movs    r0, #8
   0x08005f4e <+238>:   82 22   movs    r2, #130    ; 0x82
   0x08005f50 <+240>:   10 00   movs    r0, r2
   0x08005f52 <+242>:   51 e3   b.n 0x80065f8
   0x08005f54 <+244>:   21 12   asrs    r1, r4, #8
   0x08005f56 <+246>:   a0 21   movs    r1, #160    ; 0xa0
   0x08005f58 <+248>:   04 20   movs    r0, #4
   0x08005f5a <+250>:   82 22   movs    r2, #130    ; 0x82
   0x08005f5c <+252>:   04 00   movs    r4, r0
   0x08005f5e <+254>:   51 e3   b.n 0x8006604
   0x08005f60 <+256>:   03 20   movs    r0, #3
   0x08005f62 <+258>:   82 82   strh    r2, [r0, #20]
   0x08005f64 <+260>:   a1 20   movs    r0, #161    ; 0xa1
   0x08005f66 <+262>:   82 90   str r0, [sp, #520]  ; 0x208
   0x08005f68 <+264>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f6a <+266>:   5c e3   b.n 0x8006626
   0x08005f6c <+268>:   33 02   lsls    r3, r6, #8
   0x08005f6e <+270>:   a0 e1   b.n 0x80062b2
   0x08005f70 <+272>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f72 <+274>:   60 42   negs    r0, r4
   0x08005f74 <+276>:   1e ff 2f e1 vrhadd.u16  d14, d14, d31
   0x08005f78 <+280>:   1f ff 2f e1 vrhadd.u16  d14, d15, d31
   0x08005f7c <+284>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f7e <+286>:   a0 e1   b.n 0x80062c2 <SHIFT_TAB_CCxP+2>
   0x08005f80 <+288>:   00 00   movs    r0, r0
   0x08005f82 <+290>:   50 e3   b.n 0x8006626
   0x08005f84 <+292>:   02 01   lsls    r2, r0, #4
   0x08005f86 <+294>:   e0 c3   stmia   r3!, {r5, r6, r7}
   0x08005f88 <+296>:   02 01   lsls    r2, r0, #4
   0x08005f8a <+298>:   a0 b3   cbz r0, 0x8005ff6 <memset+66>
   0x08005f8c <+300>:   35 00   movs    r5, r6
   0x08005f8e <+302>:   00 ea 00 00 and.w   r0, r0, r0
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Division is implemented in software by a call to `__aeabi_idiv`. Are you linking the required code?

Comment: Post the disassembly?

Comment: @TomV I have added disassembly. But I am not skilled at asm language at all.

Comment: @Codo I am not sure. It is written in some standard lib? Or where should I look for it? But the code complies all good and __aeabi_idiv is used in disassembly, so I think it should be included...

Comment: It's one of the things that could go wrong. I can't tell it from the assembly file as it represents the state before linking and not a disassembly of the resulting executable. Another thing that can go wrong is the startup code, e.g. the stack pointer could not be set up. Can you use a debugger and single step it?

Comment: @Codo I may see the problem. On the second line of __divsi3 dissasembly there is jump to address `0x08005e62 <+2>: 51 e3   b.n 0x8006508`, but in the map file, last used address in flash seems to be `0x800063AC` . So it has to be some problem with linking? My flags are: `LFLAGS  = -T ls.ld -nostartfiles -mthumb -Wl,-Map=mapFile.map -Wl,-heap=0`

Comment: Something is really messed up in the first few instructions: `stmia   r0!, {r0}` but r0 at this point is zero, not a pointer where you can store anything.  What is the toolchain? and are you sure you disassembled the right library?

Comment: @TOMV I found the problem. Written in answers. But actually, I don't know the cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally a got a solution. In dissasembly I saw that function, which cares of division (__divsi3) jumps to address some weird address, which was not listed in my map file. So I checked my compile flags ans when I added `-mpu=cortex-m0plus`, everything started to work properly.